# Connecting android device with bluetooth car radio

Tags: android, bluetooth

I need to connect my android phone with a car radio via bluetooth so I could send some data(anything) that would be displayed on the car radio display. I guess this would require to open bluetooth socket to the device. I have managed so far to open socket to a small ear plug bluetooth handsfree device and receive initial message 06-25 14:22:12.995: V/Bluetooth AT recv(2293): AT+BRSF=28 and this works every time.

What do I do from here?

Comment: check out my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11168407/996493) [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8894924/996493), it will be useful for you :)

Comment: @Lucifer stream player with radio frequency is possible on android?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have found tons of code how to stream music :) but nothing regarding my problem. To make it more simple I would like to stream music and I would like the radio display to show the songs title. Any help?

Comment: @HeroVsZero , i think bluetooth connectivity is better