# Details needed for making an online streaming android app for an internet radio

Tags: android, streaming, audio-streaming

I would like to know the particular specifications needed for adding a particular online radio streaming station? I want to setup up one station first and would like to add more stations to my android app whenever I found another suitable station. So my question is what exact info is needed from a particular station for adding that station??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8894832/android-internet-radio-streaming) There are some code for how to stream a radio link.

I think you want to know which information of your station you need, right?
If you check the answer, there's a streaming link of the internet radio station. Every station has a streaming link like this with a port number (the four number at the end of the link).

This is the basic and simplest internet radio streaming way.

Comment: where can i get that link and port number??The stations I have been looking for didnt explicitly have one..is there any way to get those info from the pc browser while playing the station  on the browser??

Comment: If you can download the radio streaming file with extension like ".m3u" , open this file in an editor, for example Sublime Text. Then you will see the link in editor

Comment: Not every station specifies a port number.  Many just use plain old port 80, which is the default so it doesn't need to be specified.